# svn-git : git cat-file "not a valid object name" bad named file unfindable

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

As you may have understood i am trying to put a SVN repo on Git, and i need to keep the history.
I use this command to do it :

> git svn clone $1  --no-metadata -A authors_git.txt --stdlayout ~/temp

But sadly an error occurred, there is a tag with a space in his name and git cat-file doesn't really like it, i know that i have to replace it with "%20" but the file is not at the path given by git cat-file.

> fatal: Not a valid object name refs/remotes/tags/5.0.2 Mercanet
>
> cat-file commit refs/remotes/tags/5.0.2 Mercanet: command returned error: 128

So i did some researches (i am a trainee and i am doing it for the enterprise i am working for) and i discovered that this tag has been removed, but it is still in the history of the SVN repo (and the history is huge...) .

So here are some questions i have :

1. How can i have access to this file ?
2. How can i change its name ? (does a simple rename or cp works?)
3. Do i have to change the name for each SVN revision ?

Sorry for the bad english and thanks for reading (and maybe answering) ! Have a nice day !

Comment: PS : my Git version is : 1.8.4.5